# A way to simulate requests to the IIS without going through the network adaptor?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I want to check the performance of a single very short ASP.NET MVC3 action with different sets of Action Filters,
The way I want to do it is by bombarding my Application with as many requests as I can generate (a single call is to fast to measure accurately) and compare the results.

Problem is that the bottleneck of this test is most likely to be the network adapter,
Is there a way to send requests straight to the application so they still go through all the IIS(7) and Application call stack?

Comment: hey but what is the point to make a stress test with a load higher than the load the network interface of that web server can handle? If the Network card can only accept up to x GB/sec, your web application will most likely never get more than that load right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about a localhost benchmark (or stress test if you prefer). If your site IP is assigned to your Ethernet card switch it to 127.0.0.1. Another option is to install the MS LoopBack Adapter (a fake network card) and move (temporarily?) the IP from the Ethernet to the fake card.